# Strange characters in Htmt view

Tags: javascript, html, spring-security

I have a javascript like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var login = "<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>";
</script>
```

When i see the value of login is

```
abc&#64;gmail&#46;com.
```

What i want that it must be like `abc@gmail.com.`

Is there is a way I can get the correct lo-gin and not with some weird symbols. Also i would like to know why such weird symbols are occurring instead of proper symbols.

Comment: Those are the HTML codes for `@` and `.` http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: How i can avoid them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&#64;` and `&#46;` are the [HTML codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for `@` and `.` respectively.

As far as I know there isin't any native function to decode such string in JavaScript. However you can always use the parsing ability of DOM elements.

```
var login = (login = document.createElement('span'), login.innerHTML = 'abc&#64;gmail&#46;com', login.textContent);
```

You can wrap this functionality in a function for reuse:

```
function decodeHTML(text) {
    var el = document.createElement('span');

    return el.innerHTML = text, el.textContent; 
}

decodeHTML('abc&#64;gmail&#46;com');
```